# What is the difference between propagating and handling?

Tags: java, exception

I'm studying for a CS exam this Friday and have hit a bump in the road here.  The question asks me to handle the exception and then propagate the exception using two different methods, but I was under the impression they were the same thing.  Can anyone help?  The practice question is listed below.

You are given the following class:

```
public class ReadData {
   public void getInput() {
     getString();
     getInt();
   }

   public void getString() throws StringInputException {
     throw new StringInputException();
   }

   public void getInt() throws IntInputException {
     throw new IntInputException();
   }
}

class StringInputException extends Exception {}

class IntInputException extends Exception {}
```

The code above will result in compilation errors in getInput() method. 
Rewrite getInput() method using two different techniques:

```
Method 1 - Handle the exception 

Method 2 - Propagate the exception
```

so that the code compiles.

Answer (score 5):

They are not the same thing. Propagation basically means re-throwing the exception, that is, allowing somewhere further up in the code to handle it; generally this is done if nothing can be done about the exception at the current level. Handling the exception means catching it and actually doing something about it - informing the user, retrying, logging - but not allowing the exception to go any further.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Example {
    // a method that throws an exception
    private void doSomething() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public void testHandling() {
        try {
            doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // you caught the exception and you're handling it:
            System.out.println("A problem occurred."); // <- handling
            // if you wouldn't want to handle it, you would throw it again
        }
    }

    public void testPropagation1() throws Exception /* <- propagation */ {
        doSomething();
        // you're not catching the exception, you're ignoring it and giving it
        // further down the chain to someone else who can handle it
    }

    public void testPropagation2() throws Exception /* <- propagation */ {
        try {
            doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e; // <- propagation
            // you are catching the exception, but you're not handling it,
            // you're giving it further down the chain to someone else who can
            // handle it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"Handle the exception" means to catch it and do whatever is necessary to continue normally.

"Propagate the exception" means to not catch it and let your caller deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

dictionary.com is your friend in this one. 
Sometimes we have to deal with that pesky english language.

Handle means do something with the exception, 
abort program ,
print error,
mess around with data ...

propagate it means forward it onto someplace else i.e. re throw it.